# What is the value of $f(0)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

[image]

The white circle point implies that it's undefined but there's also a black circle point in the origin when $f=0$. So I am unsure if $f(0)$ will be $0$ or will be undefined.

Comment: That black circle point $(0,0)$ belongs to the graph of $f$. It means that $f(0)=0$. (Similarly, $f(1)=0$ and $f(2)=3$.)

Comment: (though the black circle at $(1, 0)$ seems unnecessary!)

Comment: @TheoBendit: There might be other questions attached to that drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white circle means that the value is not defined to be what the dot shows. If there was nothing more than that, that would leave $f(0)$ undefined, however now we have more, namely that there is a black dot above it, which means that the function takes the value at that point. For that reason, we have that $f(0)=0$.